# module.exports from promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

How i can assign function initPassport from turbo.then() to module.exports?

```js
function turbo() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        UsersModel.find({
            userName: 'bumblebee'
        }, function (err, userMongo) {
            userMongo.forEach(function (one) {
                resolve({
                    username: one.userName,
                    password: one.password
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

turbo.then(function (data) {
    var user = data;

    function initPassport() {
        passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
            function (username, password, done) {
                findUser(username, function (err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        return done(err);
                    }
                    if (!user) {
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                    if (password !== user.password) {
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            }
        ));
        passport.authenticationMiddleware = authenticationMiddleware;
    }
});

module.exports = ??????????;
```

module.exports = initPassport; Not work. Tell me, how should I remake this code to work?

Comment: Modules must load synchronously. You can't do that.

Comment: Just export the promise itself and wait for the value where you import it.

Comment: there are many ways to authenticate with passport most common is to use as an middleware to express routes or whatever web framework you are using. refer here for local strategy http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be accomplished a number of ways, I'll highlight 2 below.

### Method #1

Move the anonymous function beginning on the line:

```
turbo.then(function (data) {
```

To be appended inside the `turbo` function:

```
function turbo() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     ...
    })
    .then(function (data) {
     ...
    });
}
```

Then `module.exports` may be set to `turbo`.

### Method #2

Move the anonymous function to be a named definition, e.g.:

```
function authentication(data) {
    var user = data;

    function initPassport() {
        passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
            function (username, password, done) {
                findUser(username, function (err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        return done(err);
                    }
                    if (!user) {
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                    if (password !== user.password) {
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            }
        ));
        passport.authenticationMiddleware = authenticationMiddleware;
    }
}
```

Then `module.exports` could be set to something such as:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return turbo().then(authentication);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Move turbo.then into the main function turbo. Rename it to .then

```
function turbo() {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    UsersModel.find({
        userName: 'bumblebee'
    }, function (err, userMongo) {
        userMongo.forEach(function (one) {
            resolve({
                username: one.userName,
                password: one.password
            });
        });
    });
})
.then(function (data) {
var user = data;

function initPassport() {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        function (username, password, done) {
            findUser(username, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false);
                }
                if (password !== user.password) {
                    return done(null, false);
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
    ));
    passport.authenticationMiddleware = authenticationMiddleware;
   }
  });
}
```